# Vue draggable : input field

Tags: vue.js, draggable

When i try to add an custom html field inside the draggable element , this is not working
Exemple i try to add an input type radio after remove button and check this radio and dragg this row to the top , the button radio always goes back to his last first position

```
 <input type="radio" id="index" name="drone" value="index">
```

here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/amherve/nm6c25eg/5/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong, I spun up a new exmaple for you.
[Example code here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vmv145krm3)

your data needs to be formatted like this:

```js
data () {
  return {
    list: [
      { name: 'allen' }
    ]
  }
}
```

In your component, you need to declare what other components it will use:

```js
import draggable from "vuedraggable";


export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {draggable}
}
```